# Having trouble with running a command over ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, centos7

This command isn't working as expected:

```
ssh root@<machineIP> -- sh -c "echo \$\(cat /tmp/testfile\) > /testfile"
```

My intent is to copy the contents of /tmp/testfile to /testfile.  Real simple.  But I find that /testfile has nothing in it.  The file is created (in the case it doesn't exist).

echo command works fine (minus the escapes) if run from command line on the remote server.  But doesn't work when running it through ssh.  Originally I actually had a more complex command with 'sed', but simplified what wasn't working down to this.

Both remote and local servers are CentOS7.

I found I had to escape the $ and ().  Is this causing me problems?  Is not the correct way to run this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh` will take all the command parameters, join them on spaces and then run that in the remote shell.

That means that the command being executed is basically what you'd get if you replaced `ssh` with `echo`:

```
$ echo sh -c "echo \$(cat /tmp/testfile) > /testfile"
sh -c echo $(cat /tmp/testfile) > /testfile
```

The quoting is lost, so the resulting command is equivalent to `sh -c echo > /testfile` which makes it empty.

Instead, just take the command you want to run and wrap it in single quotes:

```
ssh root@host 'echo $(cat /tmp/testfile) > /testfile'
```

Make sure never to use `echo` or `$()` when copying files though. I'm assuming this is a stand-in for something better.

Comment: Yes, this *is* a stand-in for something better.  I narrowed it down to this piece and became curious to see if it would work, and found it didn't.  Your suggestion did work!  But I don't recall why I switched to use "-- sh -c".  Anyways thanks for the quick response (and correct answer).